# jQuery prevent multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have `<a>` element in the web page that loaded via ajax:

```
<div class="small-box bg-aqua">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
            <h2>___</h2>
            <p>____</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
                    <strong> Address</strong>: -
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <strong> Phone #</strong>: -
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a id="corp1" class="small-box-footer" href="1">
            More info
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

the following script will make that `<a>` element perform ajax call

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[id^="corp"]', function(e) {
    call_master('corporate/get_detail', $(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When clicking the link only **once** multiple ajax calls are generated. 
[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying/asking. Are you saying that clicking the link **once** generates multiple ajax calls? Because the code above won't do that (unless you have an invalid HTML structure nesting `a` elements).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry for late reply, that's what I mean, clicking the link only once but generates multiple ajax calls, I used the script many times but it never happened before, so it's really confusing

Comment: your call_master function can be in a loop

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil, there is no loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `$('body').on()` with `$('body').one()` and the problem solved, thanks everyone _ :)